# How to iterate through const char** variable

Tags: c++11, managed-c++

```
I want to iterate through a const char** variable.

auto temp = ReturnCharPointer();//This method return const char**
```

This pointer consists of two strings 0-"John", 1-"David".

When I trying iterate through it I am getting exception as violating access for reading.

```
for(int i=0; temp[i] != NULL; i++)
{
   printf(temp[i]);//once i's position is 2 that is no data is there, it is 
                   //throwing exception
}
```

As per the comments below, please find the below for little more explanation,

I have a C# business layer, where I have a method defined which returns string[].

In my managed c++ DLL I have referenced this C# sharp dll and trying to call this method and store the string[](in managed c++ array^) to list or vector.

C# Method:

```
public string[] ArrayofStrings()
{
     return new[] {"John", "Deer"};
}
```

Managed c++:

```
void DisplayName()
{
   auto strArray = CSharpObj.ArrayofStrings();
  //How to iterate and assign it list<string>. ????

}
```

How can I convert array^ to list or vector.

Comment: Are you sure "how can I prevent it from throwing?" is what you want to ask? There are a lot of really, _really_ bad ways to prevent it from throwing...

Comment: In C++? I would say you don't. I mean you don't use a `char**` variable, but a vector of strings instead. Then it's very easy to iterate over.

Comment: As for your problem, my crystal ball says that you probably return a pointer to a local array from your `ReturnCharPointer` function. And as such, that array goes out of scope once the function returns and the pointer will become invalid, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) if you dereference it. But hey, that's only a guess, since you haven't shown us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Like @Someprogrammerdude says, you should use [vectors, strings, and iterators](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2402b5542bf1dda6). The standard library is your friend.

Comment: Although it could be another problem, and that would be you going out of bounds of the "array" returned by the function. If you allocate memory dynamically for the `char**` variable, but only allocate enough for two elements, then the loop will continue to iterate out of bounds because there's no guarantee of any kind that `temp[2]` will be a null pointer. Going out of bounds *also* leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: If you have two strings, and your test in `for` is `temp[i] != NULL`, then you need third "string" at index `2` of value `NULL` to make the `for` terminate at `i == 2`. Then again, this is not C++, this is hardly C. In C++ using one of containers will provide you also with current size of container, so you don't need the `NULL` terminator at end.

Comment: Do you add a `NULL` value to your array of strings? If not, you must do it according to the way you're iterating it. And yes, `std::vector<std::string>` is much more C++-ish way for doing that.